# Facebook wall Image blur Issue

Tags: jquery, facebook

I am trying to copy and paste my website's link on Facebook's wall. But with website's Image it also fetch some Javascript code and show it on Facebook page. This is not happen's when I type that url manually.

Here is that code,

```
$("#target").append(''); // iterate through all the elements and create UL
options.each(function(){
    $("#target dd ul").append('' + $(this).text() + '' + $(this).val() + '');
}); // remove the select
$('#quicklink_form').hide(); // backup
```

I tried but not able to find the solution. Could anyone help me to get through this.

Answer (score 0):

Run your URL through [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and see if you've got the correct Meta Tags present on your page for Facebook's crawler - if not, fix them